# createPolicy is throwing "is not authorized to perform: iam:CreatePolicy on resource"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I have following code in java

```
String policy_doc = "{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
            }
        ]
    }";

policyArn = iam.createPolicy(
        new CreatePolicyRequest()
                .withPolicyName("do_not_delete_scheduler_policy")
                .withPolicyDocument(policy_doc))
                .getPolicy()
                .getArn()
                ;
```

> arn:aws:iam::740103494626:user/viswa is not authorized to perform: iam:CreatePolicy on resource: policy do_not_delete_scheduler_policy (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 40f4c002-d73c-11e6-86c8-6b6a4f570c83)

This can be solved by using iam:* permissions for the user. Is it possible to do without this.

Comment: You can use more fine grained permission such iam:createPolicy permission.

Comment: I didn't put the question correctly. Without using any iam policy, can we create a policy?

Comment: You can use already existing/built in policies. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#aws-managed-policies